# I want to run both functions in my switch case but only one runs; how do i fix this?

Tags: swift, switch-statement, storekit

The below function describes the paymentQueue of an In-App Purchase (IAP). When the .purchase case is selected, the 'SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)' function is run. However, the second function in that  case, 'transactionComplete()', does not.

What I want: 'SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)' function to be completed first, then run the 'transactionComplete()' function.

Background:

The 'SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)' is a void StoreKit function that completes the IAP transaction.

The 'transactionComplete()' is my own function that displays a popup view thanking the user for their purchase. This function works, just not in this scenario.

```
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for transaction in transactions {
        switch transaction.transactionState {
            case .purchased:
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                transactionComplete()
                break
            case .failed:
                print("transaction failed.")
                break
            default:
                break
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

As this was my first time using IAPs, I was experimenting with functions. Thus, it turns out I had another copy of the paymentQueue(...) function in another file that my app was reading from due to the class it belonged to being used as an observer in the AppDelegate.swift

Comment: FYI, you don't need to use `break` in Swift switches unless it's the only line in the case (as in your default instance). Breaking at the end of a case is the default behavior unless you explicitly call `fallthrough`.

Comment: `transactionComplete` should be called. Try setting a breakpoint on that line as see if it gets hit.

Comment: Can you clarify what goes on inside `transactionComplete()`? Did you set a breakpoint in `transactionComplete()` to confirm it's actually not being called or maybe it's just not running as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This method is probably not fired on the main thread.

Try using `print("isMain? \(Thread.current.isMainThread)")` to figure out if it is, if it isn't, wrap your callback like so:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    transactionComplete()
}
```